# TensorFlow Keras make ThresholdedReLU Theta optimizable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I've built a seq-to-seq model to take N periods of continuous input data and predict M periods of continuous response data (M<N). Because my response is sparse - usually 0, I want to squish predictions that are "small" to 0, so have added a Thresholded ReLU as my final layer. The model, with a single encoder and single decoder is:

```
# encoder
encoder_inputs_11 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_past, n_features))
encoder_layr1_11 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(encoderLayers[0], return_state=True)
encoder_outputs1_11 = encoder_layr1_11(encoder_inputs_11)
encoder_states1_11 = encoder_outputs1_11[1:]
# decoder
decoder_inputs_11 = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(n_future)(encoder_outputs1_11[0])
decoder_layr1_11 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(decoderLayers[0], return_sequences=True)(decoder_inputs_11, initial_state = encoder_states1_11)
decoder_outputs1_11 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_response))(decoder_layr1_11)
# threshold layer
thresh_11 = tf.keras.layers.ThresholdedReLU(theta=reluTheta)(decoder_outputs1_11)
# entire model
result = tf.keras.models.Model(encoder_inputs_11, thresh_11)
```

How can I make `theta` in `tf.keras.layers.ThresholdedReLU(theta=reluTheta)` an optimizable parameter?